# Windows Phone 7 TextBox.Height = auto in Code?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

How can set the Textbox.Height to "auto" in Code? Thank you

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I believe that Auto is `Double.NaN`

Update -

> In addition to acceptable Double values, this property can also be Double.NaN. This is how you specify auto sizing behavior in code.

from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.height.aspx

Comment: Cool - it's also worth reading that msdn post - especially about how Height, MinHeight and MaxHeight interact. And to thank someone... mark the answer as accepted and upvote it :)

Comment: Have to create an account, just one sec ;)